# "height" vs "heights"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

(1a) Mr. Wilson measured his students' height and used the data to teach them how to do statistics.

(1b) Mr. Wilson measured his students' height**s** and used the data to teach them how to do statistics.

(2a) Our height is not the same.

(2b) Our height**s** are not the same.

Which one is correct, singular plural?

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker, they all are understandable. Personally, I think you could say all of those and it would mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to such measurements, it's idiomatic to keep the noun singular:

> To measure the students' height / weight / arm length / reach / growth

So, two people would say: **We are not the same weight / height** using the singular.

but when individual parts are concerned, the plural is the norm:

> To measure their chests / feet / waists / hips

So you would say:

> Our height / weight / size is not the same.

People would still understand perfectly if you said:

> Our heights / weights are not the same.

In my experience, it's just not usual.

(I speak only from experience; I haven't been able to find sources to back up my answer)